# Django two table joint

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I used `$ python manage.py inspectdb` get the following tables from MSSQL, the **Book** table may have many pictures, so I check the **Mpeg**  table of its forignkey.

How do I get the mpeg information where ***foreignkey = book_id***

**model.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(db_column='book_id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    book_name = models.CharField(db_column='book_name', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.   
    media = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'

class Mpeg(models.Model):
    picture_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    picture_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foreignkey = models.IntegerField(db_column='foreignKey')  # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mpeg'
```

**views.py**

```
def map_player_post(request, book_id):
    book = models.Book.objects.get(book_id = book_id)
    mpeg = models.Mpeg.objects.all() #Tried filter but failed
    template = get_template('map.html')
    request_context = RequestContext(request)
    request_context.push(locals())
    if book != None:
        html = template.render(request_context)
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

**template**

```
<h4>{{book.mpeg.count}}</h4> //get the book count
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword in python!! Try to use another name for a variable.

Comment: OK,  I made a wrong example. I change the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the Book table may have many pictures

For that to work you must use a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) inside the `Mpeg` model, like this:

```
class Mpeg(models.Model):
    picture_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    picture_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', models.CASCADE)
    # remove the foreignkey = models.IntegerField(db_column='foreignKey')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mpeg'
```

Now run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` and then (after you fill some data, of course) you can do queries like this:

```
book = Book.objects.get(book_id=book_id)
mpeg = Mpeg.objects.filter(book=book)
```

[BONUS]: You can remove the `picture_id` and `book_id` fields since Django will add an `id` for you automatically. Then you can rewrite above expressions like this:

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
mpeg = Mpeg.objects.filter(book=book)
```